# Image from BO template are not displaying in email

Tags: magento2, email, wysiwyg

I call my email template from my controller and send variables to it so I don't need to rewrite the entire template (header & footer) especially because they might change during time.

So, I'm using this function in my execute() controller :

```
.....
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier(132)
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => 'frontend',
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars([
                    'email' => $email,
                    'result' => $this->resultText(
                        $result_acuity,
                        $result_astigmatism,
                        $result_contrast,
                        $result_vision_lecture,
                        $result_vision_colors,
                        $result_colors,
                        $result_DLMA
                    )
                ])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($email, $name)
                ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName)
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
....
```

Inside of it, I call my template with the id number from my BO :

```
->setTemplateIdentifier(132)
```

I receive the email correctly except for the media. Those are stored in BO wysiwyg and are correctly displaying when I do the preview temmplate (they are called in the template, not in controller)

Is there something I need to know for it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out that my project needs to be on a server for the immage to be displaying, even if they are stocked in admin backoffice wysiwyg, otherwise, any mail server will block them for security.